# Which way should I follow in SQLite in Android app

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm newbie in Android. I want to design a project that also have a database. In database, I have stable/constant tables that have already inserted before users use, and also tables that I will insert or update with the information obtained from users. I found some useful SQLite DatabaseHandler for Android. With that code, I created one table that is constant, and I inserted some information.

Here is my insert function in DatabaseHandler,

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_TEST_KART_ID, iliski.getTest_kart_id()); 
values.put(KEY_DEGERLENDIRME_KART_ID, iliski.getDegerlendirme_kart_id());
values.put(KEY_RENK, iliski.getRenk()); 
values.put(KEY_SEKIL, iliski.getSekil()); 
values.put(KEY_MIKTAR, iliski.getMiktar()); 
values.put(KEY_DIGER, iliski.getDiger()); 

db.insert(TABLE_KART_ILISKILERI, null, values);
```

and I insert with following code,

```
db.addKartIliskileri(new KartIliskileri(1,1,0,0,0,1));
```

I dont have any problem about inserting, my problem is when the project is working, the code that is above works everytime!! I mean that if I have actually 15 rows that is have to be added to table, and if the project works 2 times, I have 30 rows for that table, but I should have 15 rows!! How could I avoid that? (I want to use like in MySQL)

Comment: you should have a primary key field, which'd prevent duplicate records. or some way of checking of the data exists in the DB before you try inserting it.

Comment: using `ORM` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472166/choosing-an-orm-for-android-project-min-api-level-7

Comment: When I insert a data, I was inserting without primary key area, sqlite  increments primary key area automatically. But when I try to insert manually with primary key, it prevent duplicate records. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put the code that should be pre-populated in the same place that the database is created, such that it's only executed once (i.e. after creation of the DB).

If you extended `SQLiteOpenHelper` you can put it in the `onCreate()` after `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have that code run only during the onCreate/onUpgrade methods of your database class.