# SQLiteDatabase Android + parse.com

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform

I want to take the data from parse.com

```
public void ParseQueryMap() {
         query = new ParseQuery("MyObject"); 
         query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
              public void done(List<ParseObject> myObject, ParseException e) {
              if (e == null) {
                  for ( int i = 0; i < myObject.size(); i++) {              
                              stranaGet = myObject.get(i).getString("Country");
                              oblastGet = myObject.get(i).getString("District");
                              gorodGet = myObject.get(i).getString("City");
                     }
              } 
}
```

And I want to make all of this data into the database Android

```
DBHelper dbHelper;
 @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

            dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            String name = etName.getText().toString();
            String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

            cv.put("name", name);
            cv.put("email", email);
            Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {


        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int emailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("email");

        do {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) + 
                                 ", name = " + c.getString(nameColIndex) + 
                                 ", email = " + c.getString(emailColIndex));
          } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG, "0 rows");
        c.close();
        }

       dbHelper.close();

}

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
          super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
           db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
              + "id integer primary key autoincrement," 
              + "name text,"
              + "email text" + ");");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
      }
```

In this example, the data is taken from EditText, but I want to fill a database with a parse.com. How can this be?
UPDATE: I tried to like this

```
public void ParseQueryMap() {
             query = new ParseQuery("MyObject"); 
             query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
                  public void done(List<ParseObject> myObject, ParseException e) {
                  if (e == null) {
                      for ( int i = 0; i < myObject.size(); i++) {              
                                  stranaGet = myObject.get(i).getString("Country");
                                  oblastGet = myObject.get(i).getString("District");
                                  gorodGet = myObject.get(i).getString("City");
                                  cv.put("name",  stranaGet);
                                  cv.put("email", oblastGet);
                                  db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
                         }
                  } 
    }
```

but nothing happens

Comment: Hi,I wanted to ask if you got this to work, I tried your method as well but it didn't work for me.

Comment: me too, did you figure this out? also in case there's a complete source on git do put that up. :)

Comment: You may use an ORM like [JDXA](http://softwaretree.com/2015/products/jdxa/jdxa.html) to simplify the process of local data storage in SQLite. For example, in the ParseQueryMap method above, instantiate and populate an object (say of class Location with the city, district, and country fields) using the queried data from Parse, and save that object in the local database using the the insert method of JDXA ORM. JDXA facilitates using POJOs in you app and that simplifies your app's development, evolution, and maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method is used to read data.

To insert data, use the [insert](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) method; like this:

```
db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a better way to do it.

If you are using some [ORM engines for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472166/choosing-an-orm-for-android-project-min-api-level-7) (such as [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com)), which allow you to map database entities to java-classes, integration with parse.com is very simple and straight forward. Actually, when I discovered [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) in android, I cannot live without it any more :)

Let's assume you have your entity-class, mapped to some database table. You can add annotations to its fields for mapping them on to parse.com corresponding class fields. Then you write a code that handles these annotations accordingly.

But actually, you don't have to write the code anymore. Here is a simple implementation of the idea: https://github.com/ntoskrnl/DataSync

Feel free to contribute :)

In short, the library provides methods to convert annotated classes to `ParseObject` and vice versa. Also it provides you a simple method to synchronize your local and remote data (it uses parse `objectId` and `updatedAt` fields to decide what to do)