# Is it pertinent and efficient to use an ORM on android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, orm

I'm a java web developer and I use Spring, JPA, Hibernate at my job. I'm currently having fun on android development at home and I made a app with sqllite database.
I used SQLiteOpenHelper, contentvalues, cursors,... http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html to design and query my database.
All works well but I find it very verbose with tons of codes in contrast of using an ORM. 
I know pros/cons of an ORM in web development, not in mobile/android development.

Is it useful to use it or does it slow the phone app ? Some years (at the beginning of android), I think ORM was to heavy to be used on android but since 2015, maybe it has changed?!
If yes, what are the best today ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371538/any-good-orm-tools-for-android-development?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472166/choosing-an-orm-for-android-project-min-api-level-7?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045405/are-there-any-good-orms-preferably-jpa-implementations-that-support-sqlite-on?rq=1